# search suggestion functionality with angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to run the below code on my system but not able to get the result. but same code i was running on js fiddler it was running.

this my index.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search...">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
                {{ name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule', []);

app.controller('DefaultCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
});

app.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

Also i want to get exaxct match if i enter 'A' only the words come which is start with the letter 'A' and so on...

Comment: it giving an error TypeError: iElement.autocomplete is not a function

Comment: I am not sure if it's related, but your ng-controller name in HTML and JS files are different.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this in your `index.html`

```
<div ng-app="MyModule">
    <div ng-controller="DefaultCtrl">
        <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search...">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
                {{ name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how it will work         <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search...">

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you named your controller **DefaultCtrl**, and in HTML 
you're calling

`<div ng-controller="MyController">`

So change that to match the controller names, i.e.

`<div ng-controller="DefaultCtrl">`